# What methods are available to monitor SQL database records?

Tags: asp.net, sql, notifications, monitoring

I would like to monitor 10 tables with 1000 records per table. I need to know when a record, and which record changed.

I have looked into SQL Dependencies, however it appears that SQL Dependencies would only be able to tell me that the table changed, and not which record changed. I would then have to compare all the records in the table to find the modified record. I suspect this would be a problem for me as the records constantly change.

I have also looked into SQL Trigger's, however I am not sure if triggers would work for monitoring which record changed.

Another thought I had, is to create a "Monitoring" table which would have records added to it via the application code whenever a record is modified.

Do you know of any other methods?

EDIT: 
I am using SQL Server 2008

**I have looked into Change Data Capture which is available in SQL 2008 and suggested by Martin Smith. Change Data Capture appears to be a robust, easy to implement and very attractive solution. I am going to roll CDC on my database.**

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server? Is [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx) available?

Comment: Don't rely on the application code. As much as you'd like to believe, it's never going to be the only thing touching your data.

Comment: @Martin Smith I am using SQL Server 2008. I will have to check and see if Change Data Capture is available.

Comment: @Martin Smith I looked into CDC, it looks very promising and easy to setup. I found a great tutorial if anyone is interested: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @MartinSmith please post Change Data Capture as an answer, this is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What version and edition of SQL Server? Is Change Data Capture available? – Martin Smith

I am using SQL 2008 which supports Change Data Capture. Change Data Capture is a very robust method for tracking data changes as I would like to. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can add triggers and have them add rows to an audit table. They can audit the primary key of the rows that changed, and even additional information about the changes. For instance, in the case of an UPDATE, they can record the columns that changed.

Comment: And they will catch *all* changes made to your table, whether they were made by your application code or a bored DBA.

Comment: +1 Just to clarify, you can tell which columns were 'touched' using `UPDATE()` or the `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` bitmask, but they won't tell you if the value remained the same (as is often the case in CRUD implementations). You can see which ones actually changed in value by comparing the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables, but this can become complicated quite quickly depending on the complexity of the table and the types involved.

Answer (score 3):

Before you write/implement your own take a look at [AutoAudit](http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/) :

> AutoAudit is a SQL Server (2005, 2008) Code-Gen utility that creates
>   Audit Trail Triggers with:
>
> - Created, CreatedBy, Modified, ModifiedBy, and RowVersion (incrementing INT) columns to table
> - Insert event logged to Audit table
> - Updates old and new values logged to Audit table
> - Delete logs all final values to the Audit table
> - view to reconstruct deleted rows
> - UDF to reconstruct Row History
> - Schema Audit Trigger to track schema changes
> - Re-code-gens triggers when Alter Table changes the table

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea.You can have a flag on each table that every time a record is created or updated is filled with current datetime. Then when you notice that a record has changed set its flag to null again.Thus unchanged records have null in their flag field and you can query not null values to see which record has changed/created and when (and set their flags to null again) .